# How to process a List of Objects Using Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, model-view-controller, spring-batch

I am trying read a JSON file and read its values and Store it in a `List<Data>` object.
I am calling the List from my ItemReader class and processing it to write it to Database.

My reader looks like below:

```
public class JsonItemReaderFromULProspector implements ItemReader<Data>{
//  static String jsonFilePath = Directory.JSON_FILE_PATH;

    private int nextULPIndex;

    public JsonItemReaderFromULProspector() {
         initialize();
}

    private List<Data> finalULPData;
    private void initialize() {
        List<Data> ulpData=ReadJSONFromULP.getJsonObject();
        for(Data data:ulpData){
            finalULPData=Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(data));
            nextULPIndex=0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Data read()throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

        Data nextULPData=null;
         if (nextULPIndex < finalULPData.size()) {
             nextULPData = finalULPData.get(nextULPIndex);

             nextULPIndex++;
            }

            return nextULPData;
        }

    }
```

and my processor is a normal processor that takes `<Data,ULProspector>` as input and output.

When I am trying to write it to Database. Only one record I am able to write it to DB and it is getting exit after that.

Comment: in that case, your reader is returning only one element. Check your `read` method and make sure it returns more than one element before returning `null`.

Answer (score 0):

And I believe that Only one record that you are able to write it to DB is last record from JSON file.

Try to change this part of code

```
for(Data data:ulpData){
            finalULPData=Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(data));
            nextULPIndex=0;
        }
```

TO

```
finalULPData=Collections.unmodifiableList(ulpData);
nextULPIndex=0;
```

Comment: Getting error Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<List<Data>> to List<Data>

Comment: Yes You are correct it is the last record from the JSON that is getting saved in Database.I want to save all the records starting from first one

Comment: Hi Hemant.. I got all the records from ItemReader to Item Processor ,after replacing my code with the code suggested but getting error in Processor as below                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.dksh.spcrt.processor.ULProspectorDataProcessor.process(ULProspectorDataProcessor.java) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.dksh.spcrt.processor.ULProspectorDataProcessor.process(ULProspectorDataProcessor.java) ~[classes/:na]
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:134)

Comment: debug is recommended for NullPointerException exception in ULProspectorDataProcessor.java or you can edit your question with code of processor class.